# How to take last inserted record in oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, primary-key

I have a table called orderdetails. In that I have column named ID which is primary key. I want to take the recently added record in that table. I used to filter out the last value inserted in desc using ID since that was primary key. But here primary key is not ordered. It creates random values, so I cannot able to pick last values

```
select *
from orderdetail
where Id = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
```

Comment: ++ My table has only ID has Primary key and no timestamp related column

Comment: How is your table looking alike? If you take two records, then how would you compare them in terms of data in order to determine which of them is newer?

Comment: Looking like means? Not getting your question, Kindly elaborate!

If two records newly inserted means, need only last inserted record! @LajosArpad

Comment: You need to add a date column to the table, or use a sequence. You *can* approximate "most recent" for inserts/updates by using `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ORA_ROWSCN)` which operates on the block level using the ITL, but by no means is this reliable enough for programmatic use, not to mention totally non-performant. You'll have to add your own column and populate it to do this properly.

Comment: @SrinivasanSekar you are asking about the "newest" record in your table. That implies that we need to compare the records and find the newest of them. But you did not provide your table's structure. So, how should I provide you a well-defined comparison based on the structure of your table if you do not provide the said structure?

Answer (score 1):

To cut a long story short, you can't do that.

Not with a table you currently have, that is.

There **must** be a column which explicitly says which row was inserted last. Is it a timestamp, sequence number, identity column (which - in background - also uses a sequence) or anything else you can imagine, there just has to be such a value.

---

What can you do? Forget about rows that currently exist in that table, you can't salvage anything from that.

Alter table and add a new column; `number` datatype if you'll populate it with a sequence number, `date` datatype if you'll insert a timestamp. Note that - if you insert a lot of rows at the same time - two or more could be inserted at the same time, so a sequence might be a better choice.

Let's presume you'll use a sequence. Create it (`create sequence new_seq` would do). Then use it in every `insert` statement, manually, e.g.

```
insert into that_table (pk_column, name, created_on, new_sequence_column)
  values (f_random, 'Little', sysdate, new_seq.nextval);
```

or create a `before insert` trigger

```
create or replace trg_bi_tab
  before insert on that_table
  for each row
begin
  :new.new_sequence_column := new_seq.nextval;
end;
/
```

and modify `insert` to

```
insert into that_table (pk_column, name, created_on)
  values (f_random, 'Little');
```

(`new_sequence_column` will be automatically populated).

Then you'd e.g.

```
with temp as
  (select t.*,
     row_number() over (order by new_sequence_column desc) rn
   from that_Table
  )
select *
from temp
where rn = 1;
```

or

```
select * From that_Table
where new_sequence_column = (select max(new_sequence_column) from that_table);
```

or any other query you find appropriate.

---

P.S. Have a look at this [AskTom](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:::::P11_QUESTION_ID:912210644860) discussion; you'll see demo which shows that *none* of possibly *smart* queries (that use `ROWNUM` or `ROWID` or whatever else) simply don't work.